# How to achieve synchronization and backup using Realm Sync?

Tags: mongodb, realm, mongodb-atlas, realm-mobile-platform

I am planning to develop a cross-platform app for iOS and Android and would like to sync the data via Realm Sync. Realm Sync is serverless. Let's assume the following case: A user only has one device, uses the app, saves data and the device breaks down. Then there would be no way for that user to recover their data, since Realm Sync is just a sync and not a backup, right? But how can you implement synchronization and backup within the framework of Realm? What role does MongoDB Atlas play?

Many thanks in advance!

Note: I am an undergraduate student.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Realm **Sync** is cloud based - meaning there's a cloud based server that stores the app data remotely

The data is stored locally first and then automatically sync'd to the cloud at a later time (usually within seconds or faster). That's why Realm is considered an "offline first" database; data is stored locally (offline) and then copied/stored online.

Realm can either be a purely local only database with no cloud sync or can be a synchronized online as a "real-time" cloud database. (or both!)

When sync is used, the database that backs Realm is called MongoDB, and is a NoSQL database.

Generally speaking, when a Realm client app is developed, the SDK you choose is the *layer* between your code and objects and the MongoDB back-end database.

The SDK allows you to code in an object-oriented way without the need to directly work with the low level NoSQL objects.

You create models, relationships and the UI and the SDK takes the app data, massages it, and stores it in MongoDB as NoSQL.

As a followup so future readers don't have to read through all the comments:

> Q) what does the term "serverless" mean?

A) I like this definition

*Serverless offloads all management responsibility for backend cloud infrastructure and operations tasks - provisioning, scheduling, scaling, patching and more - to the cloud provider*

and the more straight and too the point:

*Serverless is a cloud development model that allows developers to build and run applications without having to manage servers.*

> Q) Doesn't that mean that the data is then only temporarily stored in the
> cloud

A) Not at all. As mentioned above, Realm data is always written locally first and then the SDK sync's it to the cloud. If you totally erase your device, once you reinstall and run the app, Realm will pull down the data from the server (sync)

> Q) Because the prices for Realm Sync also do not include storage space
> costs:  [Pricing](https://www.mongodb.com/pricing)

A) That link includes storage per plan and costs: In summary

Shared plan is up to 5GB, the serverless is up to 1TB and the dedicated is 4TB per shard. Then, Shared is $0/Month, Serverless is .30/million reads and dedicated is a flat $57/month.

> Q) Is it then possible to save the user data on this (an Atlas
> cluster)?

A) YES! That's the whole idea! BUT. If you're developing in Realm, it's you job to craft a great app using the SDK, and let the SDK interface with Atlas (MongoDB) on the backend. Depending on your use case you may rarely need to do anything with Atlas directly.

The big picture is that when coding with Realm, you work with objects, structures and relationships in a more much natural object-oriented way - the SDK does the heavy lifting of taking that data and 'converting' it for storage on the Realm Sync server (MongoDB Atlas) - as it ends up being NoSQL.

Comment: Many thanks for your response!

But if Realm Sync can also store user data in the cloud, what does the term "serverless" mean? Doesn't that mean that the data is then only temporarily stored in the cloud until/when the data is synchronized on the devices? Because the prices for Realm Sync also do not include storage space costs. See: https://www.mongodb.com/pricing

Comment: I have now also created an account for Realm Sync as a test and an Atlas cluster was automatically created with the app. Is it then possible to save the user data on this?

Comment: @RainerNiemann In this context, the standard "serverless" plan, pricing wise, does not include a *dedicated* server; at a high level view, it means your data is on their server but the location and handling of that data is "fluid" e.g. the physical server has variable, scalable RAM, scaleable CPU, non-dedicated diagnostics, limited regional support and I believe two daily backups. A dedicated server on the other had has 100% dedicated resources - it's essentially providing you a physical box where your data is guaranteed, ongoing backups etc.

Comment: *Doesn't that mean that the data is then only temporarily stored in the cloud until/when the data is synchronized on the devices?* no - it doesn't mean that at all. Each Realm Sync pricing model works the same way; as mentioned in my answer, ALL data is written locally and then sync'd to the server. If you review the link you provided, each Realm Sync does in fact include storage and pricing - the Shared plan is up to 5GB, the serverless (preview) is up to 1TB and the dedicated is 4TB per shard. Then, Shared is $0/Month, Serverless is .30/million reads and dedicated is a flat $57/month.

Comment: To your last question *is it then possible to save the user data on this* - yes, that's the whole idea! But I suggest building an app using one of the SDK's and let the SDK sync and store the data on the server; your best use of time is to focus on getting comfortable with coding in Realm locally first; structure, objects, relationships. Then, start integrating Realm Sync. If you want to dive in, head first, there's a entire tutorial on building a Task Tracker app with sync. Here's the Swift one [Task Tracker](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/quick-start-with-sync/)

Comment: I updated the answer with a summary of your followup questions and my answers. Be sure to accept the answer if it helped so it can help others. See [How to Accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: hello, I wanted to know one thing about realm, can realm sync with community server or it only syncs with atlas ?

Comment: @JustBeginner Realm can used as a local only database (e.g. the database is stored on the device) or can be sync'd with Atlas (the database is stored both on the device as well as in Atlas). So yes, only with Atlas if you want cloud capabilities

Comment: Important point to note regarding cluster choice when using Realm Sync. You can't use Serverless plan with Realm Sync, you can use either Shared Plan or Dedicated Server plan.